# Stock peer valuation

Tags: finance

I can display various metrics for one stock and want to know if I can do it easily for many stocks. In my example, I used Microsoft and the code works. Is there a way of setting up another list like techstocks={"MSFT","AMZN","CSCO","ORCL"} and then having the code below altered to cycle through each of the elements in techstocks to display each of the values in Stockstats?

```
Stockstats = {"BookValuePerShare","PriceToBookRatio","EarningsPerShare","PERatio"}
FinancialData["MSFT", #] & /@ Stockstats
```

Comment: Try `Function[stock, FinancialData[stock, #]& /@ Stockstats] /@ techstocks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
stockstats =
  {"BookValuePerShare", "PriceToBookRatio", "EarningsPerShare"};
techstocks = {"MSFT", "AMZN", "CSCO", "ORCL"};
FinancialData[#1, #2]& @@@ Catenate @ Outer[List, techstocks, stockstats]
```

> `{8.9, 7.25, 2.12, 40.43, 20.69, 4.9, 12.62, 2.56, 2.09, 11.81, 3.48, 2.1}`

Or if you want labeling.

```
{#1, #2, FinancialData[#1, #2]} & @@@ Catenate @ Outer[List, techstocks, stockstats]
```

> ```
> {{"MSFT", "BookValuePerShare", 8.9}, 
>  {"MSFT", "PriceToBookRatio", 7.25}, 
>  {"MSFT", "EarningsPerShare", 2.12}, 
>  {"AMZN", "BookValuePerShare", 40.43}, 
>  {"AMZN", "PriceToBookRatio", 20.69}, 
>  {"AMZN", "EarningsPerShare", 4.9}, 
>  {"CSCO", "BookValuePerShare", 12.62}, 
>  {"CSCO", "PriceToBookRatio", 2.56}, 
>  {"CSCO", "EarningsPerShare", 2.09}, 
>  {"ORCL", "BookValuePerShare", 11.81}, 
>  {"ORCL", "PriceToBookRatio", 3.48}, 
>  {"ORCL", "EarningsPerShare", 2.1}}
> ```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much.